# Is it legal to use an unexpanded parameter pack as the type of a template template parameter's non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

gcc and clang disagree about whether the following code should compile:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct tuple {};

template <typename>
struct Test;

template <
    typename... Types,
    template <Types> typename... Outer, // XXX
    Types... Inner
>
struct Test<tuple<Outer<Inner>...>> {};

template <long T> struct O1 {};
template <unsigned T> struct O2 {};

Test<tuple<O1<1>, O2<2>>> test;
```

clang accepts the code, deducing `Types = {long, unsigned}, Outer = {O1, O2}, Inner={1L, 2U}`. Structurally, this seems correct.

gcc rejects the code with a deduction failure. Interestingly, it *does* accept if `O2` is changed to take a `long` non-type template parameter, which seems inconsistent to me. It suggests that Types can be expanded if `Types = {long, long}` but not if `Types = {long, unsigned}`.

However, it's not clear to me from the standard which compiler is correct. The core question is: on the line denoted `XXX`, is it valid to have a parameter pack as the type of the template template parameter's non-type template parameter? Should it expand the way that clang claims it does?

Comment: Possibly simpler example: https://godbolt.org/z/bsdjGj37s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **not valid** because:

> a type parameter pack cannot be expanded in its **own parameter clause**.

As from [[temp.param]/17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#17):

> If a *template-parameter* is a *type-parameter* with an ellipsis prior to its optional *identifier* or is a *parameter-declaration* that declares a pack ([dcl.fct]), then the *template-parameter* is a template parameter pack. A template parameter pack that is a *parameter-declaration* whose type contains one or more unexpanded packs is a pack expansion. ... **A template parameter pack that is a pack expansion shall not expand a template parameter pack declared in the same *template-parameter-list***.

So consider the following **invalid** example:

```
template<typename... Ts, Ts... vals> struct mytuple {}; //invalid
```

The above example is **invalid because** the template type parameter pack `Ts` cannot be expanded in its own parameter list.

For the same reason, your code example is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I wasn't aware of this rule. However, the question still stands if the parameter pack is declared in a separate template-parameter-list. It appears the same compiler behavior is observed, e.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/h8zdrWdhd.

Comment: @colavitam You're welcome. This seems like a bug in clang. For your [modified example](https://godbolt.org/z/h8zdrWdhd), you can ask a separate question and perhaps tag `clang` so that those people can confirm that whether or not it is a bug.

Comment: Follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71457251/4407064